# How to get Lowest and largest value after groupby in sql

Tags: mysql

I need to List the unique year and value for years with the highest value or lowest value of the score dimension of the index goal_id.  List your answer in ascending order by year and descending order by value.

Tables in database:
Goal (goal_id, goal_description)
Subgoal (subgoal_id, goal_id)
Region (region_id, region_name)
Ocean_Health (year, goal_id, dimension, region_id, value)

```
SELECT DISTINCT year, MIN(value) as 'Value'
from ocean_health
where dimension = 'score' AND goal_id = 'index'
group by year
ORDER BY year ASC, value DESC;
```

| Year | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2012 | 48.57 |
| 2015 | 50.74 |
| 2018 | 46.78 |
| 2021 | 49.14 |

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT year, MAX(value) as 'Value'
from ocean_health
where dimension = 'score' AND goal_id = 'index'
group by year
ORDER BY year ASC, value DESC;
```

| Year | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2012 | 94.57 |
| 2015 | 94.45 |
| 2018 | 94.48 |
| 2021 | 93.99 |

---

Answers I want to get :

| Year | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2012 | 94.57 |
| 2018 | 46.78 |

Comment: How is it possible that the same query returns 2 different results?

Answer (score 0):

Use `union` to combine two different results.
But I don't know why try another way to show `min(value)`, the result's year column always shows me 2012. So I used `row_number` to choose answer.

```
select year, Value 
  from (SELECT DISTINCT row_number() over(order by Value) as rw,year, 
               MIN(value) as 'Value'
          from ocean_health 
         where dimension = 'score' AND goal_id = 'index' 
      group by year
      ORDER BY year ASC, value DESC) as a
 where a.rw=1
 union
select year,Value 
  from (SELECT DISTINCT row_number() over(order by Value DESC) as rw,year, 
               Max(value) as 'Value' from ocean_health 
         where dimension = 'score' AND goal_id = 'index' 
      group by year 
      ORDER BY year ASC, value DESC) as b
 where b.rw=1
order by year;
```